# How to Set Animation Delay on Pure CSS News Ticker

Tags: html, css, css-animations, delay

I have small Pure CSS script that fade slides one after one.
Problem is, that i cant set it to wait 10s between each slide.
Again, it is Pure CSS, so, no JS.

I try to add **animation-delay** to the first slide but it dosent work.

It just replace between the slides in 1 second.

How do i set that delay, so the slide 1 will stay in 10 seconds and after that will change to slide 2 ?

```css
.slider {
  min-width: 560px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slide1,
.slide2,
.slide3,
.slide4,
.slide5 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide1 {
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.slide2 {
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade2 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade2 8s infinite;
}

.slide3 {
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade3 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade3 8s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes fade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  33.333% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  66.666% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'>test</div>
  <div class='slide2'>test2</div>
  <div class='slide3'>test3</div>
</div>
```

Here's a Live one: [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/bfqy1mas/23/)

Comment: Not really clear what is the expected result. Should it be *["test1" visible for 10s]then["test2" visible for 8s]then["test3" visible for 8s]then["test1" visible for 10s]etc.*?

Comment: Yes. Except everyone need to be visible for 10s

Comment: visible like [fully visible](https://jsfiddle.net/bfqy1mas/48/) or [fading in for 10s](https://jsfiddle.net/bfqy1mas/50/)?

Comment: By visible i mean that the slide 1 will be display for 10s, and fade (1s) right after to slide 2 that again will be display for 10s and so..

Comment: So without fade-in (going directly from opacity 0 to opacity 1)? Ps: I edited my previous comment with one more fiddle.

Comment: Bingo! The "fading in for 10s" that is the solution i need! Please set it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing when dealing with CSS animations (and with coding in general) is to *keep it simple*, and that's not always an easy task.

Let's decompose your animation a bit and flatten what you've got and what you need.

```
time     —  0s    8s    10s    18s   20s   28s   30s   38s
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––----
slide1   -  0     1      0      0     0     0     0     1  ...
slide2   -  0     0      0      1     0     0     0     0  ...
slide3   -  0     0      0      0     0     1     0     0  ...
```

From this we can see that all slides will actually use the same animation's keyframes. The only difference is when the first key will kick in (`t`).

```
time     -    t+0s    t+8s    t+10s   t+Total(otherAnimationsTime)
slide(n) -      0       1       0         start again
```

We can then set up a single *@keyframes{}* block, and set the different events relative to the total duration of all animations.

In your case, 10s per element x 3 = 30s total animation time.

In our *@keyframes*, we can then convert our time values to pecentage of the whole animation:

```
percentage = time_value / total_time * 100

0s => 0%;
8s => 8 / 30 * 100 = 26.6%
10s => 10 / 30 * 100 = 33.3%
```

Then all we have to do is to set the `t` first frame delay to each element.

```css
.slide1, .slide2, .slide3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade 30s linear infinite;
}

.slide1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.slide2 {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.slide3 {
  animation-delay: 20s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  /* assumes a total duration of 3(0)s */
  0% { opacity: 0; } /* 0s */
  26.6% { opacity:1; } /* 8s */
  33.3% { opacity:0; } /* 10s */
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'>test</div>
  <div class='slide2'>test2</div>
  <div class='slide3'>test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this answer the slides fade slowly- i need it to fade quickly

Comment: @StackBuck it is the same code as in the fiddle you said was correct. If you need to set a faster fade-in then simply integrate a frame at desired position, e.g for 2s would be `6.6%{opacity:1}`.